# Why doesn't clang/llvm optimize this?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, compiler-optimization

When compiling this code with clang 3.9:

```cpp
constexpr bool is_small(long long v) {
  return v < 0x4000000000000000;
}
int foo();
int f(int a) {
  if (is_small(a)) return a;
  else return foo();
}
```

it produces assembly equivalent to `int f(int a) { return a; }`, since it determined that `is_small(a)` will always be true, since `a` is an `int`, which (on my platform) is always smaller than `0x4000000000000000`.

When I change `is_small` to:

```cpp
constexpr bool is_small(long long v) {
  return v >= -0x4000000000000000;
}
```

the exact same happens, as expected.

However, when I change `is_small` to check both conditions:

```cpp
constexpr bool is_small(long long v) {
  return v < 0x4000000000000000 && v >= -0x4000000000000000;
}
```

clang doesn't optimize the `if` and the `return foo()` part away.

(Here's the above snippets on Godbolt, to play around with: https://godbolt.org/g/fnoE9A)

Why does this happen? It clearly concluded that the conditions individually are always true, why doesn't this extend to the logical conjunction of both?

Comment: @tkausl: That's the logical or, not logical and. With `condition1 || condition1` it also optimizes it.

Comment: Right.. I'm dumb.

Comment: There are a lot of things that any given compiler won't perfectly optimise. You've found one of them. I don't think this is really answerable beyond "because the compiler isn't perfect".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good reason, it is a missing optimization from LLVM. Filed https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=30794 to make sure it gets fixed.

Basically LLVM is first optimizing `is_small` before inlining it and optimizing the use in f(). The issue that when optimizing `is_small` it is turning the comparison `v < 0x4000000000000000 && v >= -0x4000000000000000` into `v + 0x4000000000000000 > -1`. After inlining, this new form is not recognize by the optimizer in a way that allows to constant fold the code in f().

Comment: Ah! I didn't understand why it didn't reduce `always_true && always_true` to `always_true`, but apparently it doesn't even get to that first part because of another optimzation. Thanks for explaining and filing the bug.